# How do I link my executable to my test bundle when debugging test using otest?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode, ocunit, octest

I'm using kind of a hybrid of Chris Hanson's excellent Xcode unit testing guide.

My program is a (command-line) application (which precludes using the executable itself to run the tests), but I need to be able to debug my unit tests.

So what I have is as follows:

Create test bundle and tests.
Create new test target, set bundle loader and test host.
Add main target as direct dependency for test target.
Create new custom executable otest.
Add `-SenTest self`, `MyTestBundle.octest`, arguments.
Add `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` variables in environment.

My issue is that when I now try to debug a test by running the executable, the classes referenced by the tests are not available. For instance if I write a test for class Foo, as soon as I instantiate Foo in my test I get a bad access exception.

If I add Foo.m to the test target this goes away, but I'd rather not have to add every class I want to test to the test taget as well as the application target.

I assume I just need to add a variable of some sort telling otest where to find the classes in my main executable, but I don't know what the name of this argument would be.

Can somebody point me in the right direction for fixing this?

Comment: I'm more or less in the same (floundering) boat as you are so I have little to offer, except that SenTest's parameters are capitalized in the documentation, as in -SenTest Self.

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, would the XCInjectBundle and XCInjectBundleInto variables help? They are described in Apple's [Automated Unit Testing with
Xcode 3 and Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/tools/unittestingwithxcode3.html)

> XCInjectBundle: Unit Tests.octest
>
> XCInjectBundleInto: OCT.app/Contents/MacOS/OCT